# Performance issue showing list of images from CoreData with SwiftUI from Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

I have the following view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ImagesView : View
{
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var objectContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Photo.date, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
    private var photos: FetchedResults<Photo>

    @State private var gridHeight = 180.0

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            ScrollView(.horizontal)
            {
                LazyHGrid(rows: [GridItem(.fixed(gridHeight))], alignment: .top, spacing: 0)
                {
                    ForEach(photos)
                    { photo in
                        if let data = photo.filteredData
                        {
                            Image(data: data)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 200)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running this code on an iOS 16.x device all seems fine.
On an iOS 17.x device **running from Xcode 15.2** however it takes quite long before the app becomes responsive. And, I see following message being printed when I open the tab this view is on and when scrolling through the images:

```
[0x10a022200] Created session
[0x10a025600] Created session
[0x10a028a00] Created session
[0x0] Releasing session
[0x0] Releasing session
[0x10612b600] Releasing session
[0x10a030200] Releasing session
[0x10a028a00] Releasing session
[0x10a022200] Releasing session
[0x0] Releasing session
[0x0] Releasing session
[0x106151c00] Created session
[0x10615bc00] Created session
[0x106151c00] Releasing session
[0x0] Releasing session
[0x10706da00] Created session
[0x107091800] Created session
[0x10706da00] Releasing session
[0x0] Releasing session
[0x10b858c00] Created session
```

When running the app on iOS 17.x device outside of Xcode, all is fine.

Is there a serious performance issue with the above code?
How could running from Xcode cause the long delays?
What could be causing these iOS logs?

Comment: `photo.filteredData`: You save `Data` objects directly in CoreData? You don't save them locally in "folders" as file, and have a property in your model entity to retrieve the path?

Comment: @Larme With *Allows External Storage* enabled I let CoreData sort this all out. Makes life easy and image data will be lazily loaded (if CoreData decided it was large enough to offload to external storage; which I think it will with images).

Comment: Ok, good SwiftData solution then to handle the issue.

Comment: @Larme I'm using CoreData, not SwiftData, as is in the title.